# Передать данные из JavaScript в PHP

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping

Есть код на JavaScript

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.app({appId: 'com.google.android.apps.translate'})
  .then(console.log, console.log);
```

Этот код скрапит вот это приложение: com.google.android.apps.translate. Как мне передать результат скрапинга в PHP, чтобы отобразить его на своём веб-сайте?

Comment: В php можно отправить через ajax, только не понятно для чего. Если вам нужно отобразить результат на сайте то и отображайте яваскриптом тут же.

Answer (score 0):

Если надо передать параметры из JS в PHP, то только через get / post параметры, вроде этого:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['js_param'])) {
        echo "Значение JavaScript-переменной: ". $_GET['js_param'];
    } else {
?>
    var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
        gplay.app({appId: 'com.google.android.apps.translate'}).then(handler(param) {
        document.location.href=location.href + '?js_param=' + param
        });
<?php } ?>
```

Не уверена, что существуют другие способы.
Если на странице есть еще промисы или колбеки, то дожидаемся всех ответов, собираем все параметры и скопом передаём.